# How to efficiently use the std::osyncstream objects?

Tags: c++, multithreading, io, c++20, thread-synchronization

There is an example code on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_osyncstream/basic_osyncstream) on how to use `std::osyncstream` class:

```
#include <string_view>
#include <syncstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
 
void worker(const int id, std::ostream &os) {
  std::string_view block;
  switch (id) {
    default: [[fallthrough]];
    case 0: block = "██"; break;
    case 1: block = "▓▓"; break;
    case 2: block = "▒▒"; break;
    case 3: block = "░░"; break;
  }
  for(int i = 1; i <= 50; ++i) {
    os << block << std::flush;
  }
  os << std::endl;
}
 
int main() {
  std::cout << "Synchronized output should not cause any interference:" << std::endl;
  {
    auto scout1 = std::osyncstream{std::cout};
    auto scout2 = std::osyncstream{std::cout};
    auto scout3 = std::osyncstream{std::cout};
    auto scout4 = std::osyncstream{std::cout};
    auto w1 = std::jthread{worker, 0, std::ref(scout1)};
    auto w2 = std::jthread{worker, 1, std::ref(scout2)};
    auto w3 = std::jthread{worker, 2, std::ref(scout3)};
    auto w4 = std::jthread{worker, 3, std::ref(scout4)};
  }
 
  std::cout << "\nLack of synchronization may cause some interference on output:" << std::endl;
  {
    auto w1 = std::jthread{worker, 0, std::ref(std::cout)};
    auto w2 = std::jthread{worker, 1, std::ref(std::cout)};
    auto w3 = std::jthread{worker, 2, std::ref(std::cout)};
    auto w4 = std::jthread{worker, 3, std::ref(std::cout)};
  }
}
```

Now my question is simple: What is the most efficient (in terms of runtime speed) way of using these objects for each individual thread of execution? In the above example, they are constructed at the call site and then passed to the threads by reference (BTW, how does `std::ostream &os` bind to objects of type `std::osyncstream{std::cout}`?). On the other hand, in my small program, I have tried constructing an individual local `std::osyncstream{std::cout}` object in each function and then writing to it, which works okay. This way I did not have to pass them by reference to the functions (like the above code).

So what is the rule for creating these objects? How many do we need to create and where? I currently have a small program that runs two unrelated `std::jthread`s simultaneously both of which call multiple functions (8 for each `jthread`) sequentially which try to write to `std::cout`. I need to prevent the interleaving of text. Right now, each of those 16 functions writes to `cout` via a `std::osyncstream{std::cout} << "like this\n";`. The size of the executable doubled after I added those `osyncstream` objects. So it seems that this is not the optimal approach at all. Should I have a single `std::osyncstream` object in each `jthread` function and then pass it by reference to its 8 internal functions which run sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> BTW, how does `std::ostream &os` bind to objects of type `std::osyncstream{std::cout}`?)

same as how any reference to `Base` binds to expressions of type `Derived`

> So what is the rule for creating these objects? How many do we need to create and where?

Each separate `osyncstream` object holds a separate `syncbuf` (and a bunch of other state that every `ostream` holds) which holds a separate heap-allocated byte buffer (plus a couple flags and the pointer to cout's mutex).
So if you're always using ad-hoc temporaries (`std::osyncstream{std::cout} << "like this\n";`) you're destroying and re-creating all that state and all those buffers, likely unnecessarily. The original code avoided that futile work by allocating a single `osyncstream` per thread.

Comment: So you say it's good to create one of these objects for each thread and then pass them to the threads? This is what I eventually did and it reduced the size of the executable significantly.